# Pra que serve e como usar Netscape HTTP Cookie File?

Tags: php, cookies

Preciso salvar `cookies` de algumas contas que autenticarem meu APP no Twitter, procurei na web e encontrei algo do tipo:?

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# https://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

#HttpOnly_.twitter.com  TRUE    /   TRUE    0   _twitter_sess   BAh7DCIKZmxhc2hJQzonQWN0aW9uQ29udHJvbGxlcjo6Rmxhc2g6OkZsYXNo%250ASGFzaHsABjoKQHVzZWR7ADoPY3JlYXRlZF9hdGwrCE5GrqRcAToMY3NyZl9p%250AZCIlNDAyMmVkNWY3ZmNiYzdmNGIwZjM5NTZhOTM4ODU1MmM6B2lkIiU1YWJm%250AMWEzYmUxZWM3MmUwYzgzZjZlNzE1MTYwOWU5MjofbG9naW5fdmVyaWZpY2F0%250AaW9uX3VzZXJfaWRsKwdWcHFVOiJsb2dpbl92ZXJpZmljYXRpb25fcmVxdWVz%250AdF9pZCIlSDUyNDduWjdMZThhVVZkY21mWEw1YVVlT0ZaUnNYTHI6CXVzZXJs%250AKwdWcHFV--5148e6c684aadb571a79e48480b6c65398770db9
.twitter.com    TRUE    /   TRUE    1497433103  ct0 b59149399feb3cb9bf073a4f6c8ac99f
.twitter.com    TRUE    /   FALSE   1560483503  guest_id    v1%3A149741150369212010
.twitter.com    TRUE    /   FALSE   1812771541  ads_prefs   "HBERAAA="
#HttpOnly_.twitter.com  TRUE    /   TRUE    1544672341  kdt eyYcfbtxCwHOWoJ2f2cqPC7CozDRWdoddbgMIWnM
.twitter.com    TRUE    /   FALSE   1812771541  remember_checked_on 0
.twitter.com    TRUE    /   TRUE    0   twid    "u=1433497686"
#HttpOnly_.twitter.com  TRUE    /   TRUE    0   auth_token  4faa69fd29e85734f2db445239d0e0d81a6d7afc
twitter.com FALSE   /   FALSE   0   lang    pt
```

Isso eu achei neste domínio: http://twitterlike.com.br/api/cookie/

Gostaria de saber como fazer e pra que serve **NetScape HTTP Cookie File**.

Comment: Isso é um formato de cookie, normalmente isso é o resultado do `cookie-jar`, do cURL, que salva neste formato. Porém, nesta situação isso é uma vulnerabilidade extremamente alta do site, aparentemente. Porque esses arquivos são os cookies de acesso as contas do twitter, basicamente com eles você pode acessar as 10702 contas, se estiverem válidas. O `_twitter_sess` e o `auth_token` é quem autoriza o acesso, ou seja se você automaticamente ou manualmente definir esses cookies para os respectivo valores (`Bah7D...` e `4faa69...`) você poderá acessar o twitter dessa pessoa.

Comment: Ta eu preciso fazer exatamente igual sem inteções maliciosas, você sabe um jeito? de fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto é um formato de armazenamento de cookies e neste caso foi feito usando o cURL, como mencionado nos comentário `This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.`.

---

### Para que ele serve?

Como uma forma de armazenar cookies. Todas as informações essenciais, desde qual é o domínio, qual o nome do cookie, qual é o valor do cookie, se contem a *flag*  de seguro, se contem a *flag* de HTTPOnly... Neste situação existe uma página que utiliza login/senha, do Twitter, você envia uma requisição para fazer o login e então armazena os cookies, para que em futuras requisições você utilize estes cookies.

Os cookies servem para vários propósitos, muito além de login/senha. Se você sabe o que são cookies e para que eles são usados e como eles funcionam, então você sabe a razão de armazena-los.

### Como eu gero um arquivo desses?

Isso está na documentação do cURL, utilize:

```
curl -c /caminho/arquivo.txt https://site.com
```

Isso irá salvar os cookies de `https://site.com` no caminho especificado, para usar os cookies utilize o `-b`. [Mais informações veja na documentação.](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)

No caso do PHP utilize:

```
$curl = curl_init('https://seusite.com');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'caminho/arquivo.txt');
//...

curl_exec($curl);
```

Isso irá fazer com que salve os cookies no arquivo especificado. Depois, para uma futura requisição usar esses cookies utilize `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` ao invés do `COOKIEJAR`.

*O `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` irá ler o arquivo e enviar eles no cabeçalho de `Cookie:`, ele suporta os antigos formatos do Netscape/Mozilla e também um arquivo contendo o `Set-Cookies:`.*

Você tem várias e várias outra formas, inclusive mais eficientes, de obter/armazenar os cookies da página, uma das outras formas é simplesmente obtendo a informação diretamente do cabeçalho, do `Set-Cookie:`.

Comment: Tudo bem, gostei da resposta, bem elaborada, parabéns, mas outra dúvida, eu estou usando abraham/twitteroauth, não utilizo esta forma do usuário inserir usuário e senha, e sim clicando no botão pra autenticar, guardo o token de acesso em uma tabela, funciona da mesma forma?

Comment: Não. Os cookies somente será obtido se fizer a requisição usando login/senha. Para isso basta que você entre na página do Twitter veja qual é o URL chamado (ou seja F12 > Network) e faça a requisição usando cURL, ele é capaz de enviar as informações *iguais* ao navegador. A API oficial do Twitter não utiliza cookies, até porque você obter login/senha de outras pessoas não é seguro, para isso existe o OAuth, disponibilizado oficialmente pelo Twitter.

Comment: Entendi, então vou ter que recorrer login/senha e guardar dinheiro pra sair da cadeia depois.

Comment: mas a pagina que vc diz é de login, ou já logado ?

Comment: poderia responder?

Comment: Bem, se você quer obter os cookies você não terá como acessar uma página logada sem ter os cookies. Logo, o que você precisa é fazer a requisição de login, para `https://twitter.com/sessions` no caso, é ele quem recebe os dados de login. Se a combinação de login/senha estiver certa o Twitter irá retornar os cookies associados a conta, que irá permitir acessar o perfil do Twitter, você deve armazena-los. Armazenando permitirá fazer as outras requisições como se estivesse conectado neste usuário. Todo o processo neste caso deve ser feito usando cURL *ou outro software equivalente*.

Comment: obg, com esses comentários e respostas acho que consigo fazer o que eu quero...