# Como obter informações para fomulário vindo do Twitter?

Tags: php, oauth2, oauth, twitter-api

Ontem eu fiz [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/215513/pra-que-serve-e-como-usar-netscape-http-cookie-file) aqui no **SoPT**, eu estou agora seguindo o que o *Inkeliz* Disse:

> Os cookies somente será obtido se fizer a requisição usando login/senha. Para isso basta que você entre na página do Twitter veja qual é o URL chamado (ou seja F12 > Network) e faça a requisição usando cURL, ele é capaz de enviar as informações iguais ao navegador. A API oficial do Twitter não utiliza cookies, até porque você obter login/senha de outras pessoas não é seguro, para isso existe o OAuth, disponibilizado oficialmente pelo Twitter.

A questão é a seguinte como posso fazer isto? Teria como fazer usando TwitterOAuth?

Alguém daria um exemplo de como fazer esta requisição, usando **f12 > Tetwork**?

Meu código de autenticação é este:

```
<?php

class Auth {

    public function signedIn() {

        if (isset($_SESSION['twitter_access_token'])) {
            $access_token = $_SESSION['twitter_access_token'];

            $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);

            $user = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');

            return $user;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function getAuthUrl() {

        $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);

        $request_token = $connection->getRequestToken(OAUTH_CALLBACK);

        if($request_token){
            $token = $request_token['oauth_token'];

            $_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $token ;
            $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];

            $auth_url = $connection->getAuthorizeURL($token);
        }

        return $auth_url;
    }

    public function getAccessToken() {

        $request_token = [];
        $request_token['oauth_token']           = $_SESSION['oauth_token'];
        $request_token['oauth_token_secret']    = $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'];

        if (isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && $request_token['oauth_token'] !== $_GET['oauth_token']) {
            die('Error: Something went wrong...');
        }

        $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $request_token['oauth_token'], $request_token['oauth_token_secret']);

        $access_token = $connection->getAccessToken($_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']);

        if (empty($access_token)) {
            die('Error: Invalid access token...');
        }

        return $access_token;
    }

    public function logout() {
        session_destroy();
        header('Location:' . URL_BASE);
    }

}
```

A pergunta agora é a seguinte, como obter os dados, comparando `user = oauth_token` e `password = oauth_token_secret` e confirmar no formulário?

```
<form method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="ttrUsername" placeholder="Usuário do Twitter" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" name="ttrPassword" placeholder="Senha do Twitter" class="form-control">
  </div>

  <button type="submit" name="ttrSignin" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
    <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> Entrar agora
  </button>
</form>
```

Este é meu formulário:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Peguei o seguinte `cURL`

```
curl "https://twitter.com/"
-H "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br"

-H "accept-language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4"

-H "upgrade-insecure-requests: 1"

-H "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.109 Safari/537.36"

-H "accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8"

-H "cache-control: max-age=0"

-H "authority: twitter.com"

-H "cookie: guest_id=v1^%^3A149848156157534036; privacy_2017=1; lang=pt; eu_cn=1; ct0=3dae64dcfd1d4e31e6b9f749eaff5f1c; _gat=1; ads_prefs=^\^"HBERAAA=^\^"; kdt=6F5z2H1dYzkK2dxVkhDommOOBWmYJiXTdCCbRZGE; remember_checked_on=1; twid=^\^"u=866687457990979584^\^"; auth_token=115ba1614d21781e601769c512a48bccc7bda89b; _ga=GA1.2.1124081759.1498481564; _gid=GA1.2.126286429.1498481564; _twitter_sess=BAh7CiIKZmxhc2hJQzonQWN0aW9uQ29udHJvbGxlcjo6Rmxhc2g6OkZsYXNo^%^250ASGFzaHsABjoKQHVzZWR7ADoPY3JlYXRlZF9hdGwrCOgPduRcAToMY3NyZl9p^%^250AZCIlZWM4NWI1ZTZiMDk5Yzg4MDZmM2NhNGE4MTA5MGZmODY6B2lkIiVlM2I4^%^250AMTRmNDA4NTZlYTkyYzI1Y2Y3NDE1NTE2ZjYwYjoJdXNlcmwrCQCw1rCmFwcM--b7e62a94a232a36015e8959d2391af44b9b2b753"

-H "referer: https://twitter.com/login/error?redirect_after_login=^%^2F" --compressed
```

Fiz o seguinte esquema, e está retornando a página de login do twitter:

```
<?php

# First call gets hidden form field authenticity_token
# and session cookie
$ch = curl_init();
$sTarget = "https://twitter.com/";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $sTarget);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://twitter.com/");
$html = curl_exec($ch);

# parse authenticity_token out of html response
preg_match('/<input type="hidden" value="([a-zA-Z0-9]*)" name="authenticity_token"\/>/', $html, $match);
$authenticity_token = $match[1];



$username = "your@email.com";
$password = "password";

# set post data
$sPost = "session[username_or_email]=$username&session[password]=$password&return_to_ssl=true&scribe_log=&redirect_after_login=%2F&authenticity_token=$authenticity_token";

# second call is a post and performs login
$sTarget = "https://twitter.com/sessions";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $sTarget);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $sPost);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));

# display server response
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: Acho que meu comentário responde todas as perguntas. Primeiro, o que eu quero dizer com "F12 > Network" é que você veja como a requisição é feita, então refaça ela no cURL, inclusive o Chrome permite que copie em "Copy All as cURL". Você também pode usar o Burp Suite... O OAuth não usa login/senha, em seu lugar utiliza um "token". Bem, acredito que o seu problema seja não entender o básico de como as requisições HTTP funcionam. Além disso se soubesse o que é o OAuth saberia que ele [foi feito para não usar login/senha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/134361/15089).

Comment: Bom, eu entendo o básico e sim, sei que foi feito para não usar login/senha. só queria saber uma maneira, de como faze-lo... um exemplo de código... simples que seja...

Comment: Vish essa tela é a maior pescaria! Você não pode pedir as credenciais para o usuário, isso é *phishing* (por exemplo isso te daria o poder de acessar a conta dos seus usuários). Faça login num site via twitter para entender – você digita suas credenciais no popup do twitter.com e nunca no site que integra. Veja a documentação do Twitter para fazer isso. https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in/implementing

Comment: @rodorgas verei, editei o tópico com o cURL que peguei com a dica do Inkeliz

Comment: Puts... muda sua senha mano, seu twitter foi comprometido. Não se posta cookie de sessão, isso é segredo. Sério, leia as paradas, segurança é uma área da computação que não dá pra improvisar.

Comment: rlx, essa conta aí ta liberada pra geral usar... criei de propósito. fiz pra testar...

Comment: editei o tópico.

Comment: @rodorgas, teria como me informar, como utilizar estes cookies para postar como fizeram  na minha conta?

Comment: Como ele postou o cookie de sessão dele, quem usar esse cookie vai sequestrar a sessão dele. Veja https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking. Você pode alterar seu cookie de sessão nas configurações do navegador.

Comment: @rodorgas consegui, é possível fazer algun script pra seguir os cookies e sessões salvas no meu banco de dados?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Esta resposta é antes da edição, baseado no [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/215762/como-obter-informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-para-fomul%C3%A1rio-vindo-do-twitter?noredirect=1#comment440874_215762).

Se quer um exemplo, então suponha que você tem website X, que usa este código:

```
<?php
/**
 * NÃO UTILIZE ESTE CÓDIGO EM PRODUÇÃO!
 */

session_start();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    if (isset($_POST['nome'], $_POST['senha'], $_POST['csrf'], $_SESSION['csrf'])
        && hash_equals($_POST['csrf'], $_SESSION['csrf'])
    ) {

        if (hash_equals($_POST['senha'], '123456789')) {
            $_SESSION['nome'] = $_POST['nome'];
        }

    }

}


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {

    $_SESSION['csrf'] = $_SESSION['csrf'] ?? base64_encode(random_bytes(64));

    if (isset($_SESSION['nome'])) {

        echo 'Você está logado usando o nome de ', $_SESSION['nome'];

    } else {


        echo '<form method="post">';

        echo '<input name="nome" type="text" placeholder="Nome">';
        echo '<br>';
        echo '<input name="senha" type="password" placeholder="Senha">';
        echo '<br>';
        echo '<input name="csrf" type="hidden" value="' . $_SESSION['CSRF'] . '">';
        echo '<input name="enviar" type="submit">';

        echo '</form>';

    }

}
```

Então ele tem três coisas:

1. Se for POST e o login correto: define a sessão.
2. Se for GET:

   1. Estiver conectado (existe sessão contendo o `Nome`): mostra o seu nome.
   2. Estiver desconectado: mostra o formulário.

---

Supondo que você sabe o básico de como funciona o HTTP e que entenda minimante de cURL, então:

```
curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1/login.php -v
```

Irá retornar o mesmo resultado de quando acessamos via navegador, o mais importante neste caso são duas coisas:

```
< Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=3qsmtd817pof4ucngd3f9tjf1e; path=/
```

Este é *cookie* enviado pelo servidor ao cliente, depois temos o `input` que contem o `csrf-token`, em:

```
<input name="csrf" type="hidden" value="6kYwBSjY8lfKcXefUau3r6apgcY3fsjEbEhiPjlt1lxZwXuwDzJeYh6F1WyW4q/kycj4/YczxHxXC0t0YtUmhg==">
```

Mas, ainda precisamos ver para onde os dados são enviados, *ignorando o form do html*, no console em "Network" ao clicar em "Enviar" é mostrado qual a página é chamada e qual o método e quais os cabeçalhos.

Então fazemos o mesmo no CURL:

```
curl ^
-X POST ^
-d "nome=Inkeliz&senha=123456789&csrf=6kYwBSjY8lfKcXefUau3r6apgcY3fsjEbEhiPjlt1lxZwXuwDzJeYh6F1WyW4q/kycj4/YczxHxXC0t0YtUmhg==" ^
-H "Cookie: PHPSESSID=3qsmtd817pof4ucngd3f9tjf1e" ^
http://127.0.0.1/login.php -v
```

> Significados:

- `-X` define o método (é redundante neste caso!).
- `-d` define o "corpo" da requisição, neste caso é um `x-www-form-urlencoded`.
- `-H` define o cabeçalho, no caso o cookie anteriormente obtido.
- `-v` exibe todo o cabeçalho de envio e de resposta e outras informações, como de handshake no caso do HTTPS.

Agora desde que usamos o mesmo cookie:

```
curl ^
-X GET ^
-H "Cookie: PHPSESSID=3qsmtd817pof4ucngd3f9tjf1e" ^
http://127.0.0.1/login.php
```

Iremos obter:

```
Você está logado usando o nome de Inkeliz
```

---

Como fazer isso em PHP existem duas etapas.

Primeiro precisamos pegar o CSRF-Token (e o cookie, que tem relação direta com o CSRF-Token):

```
$cookie = '';
$csrf = '';

$PegarCSRFToken = curl_init('http://127.0.0.1/login.php');

curl_setopt_array($PegarCSRFToken, [
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION => function($curl, $cabeçalho) use (&$cookie){

            if(stripos($cabeçalho, 'Set-Cookie:') === 0){
                if(preg_match('/Set-Cookie:\s?(.*?);/i', $cabeçalho, $matches)) {
                    $cookie .= $matches[1] . '; ';
                }
            }

            return strlen($cabeçalho);
        }
    ]
);

$PegarCSRFToken = curl_exec($PegarCSRFToken);

if(preg_match('/name="csrf".*?value="(.*?)"/', $PegarCSRFToken, $matches)){

    $csrf = $matches[1];

}
```

Acredito que ele esteja fácil e entender, obvio que pode ser melhorado, mas o ponto é:

1. Ele obtêm o cookie e armazena em `$cookie` usando o `CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION`, extraindo usando `preg_match` no `Set-Cookie:` enviado pelo servidor.
2. Ele obtêm o CSRF-Token usando o `preg_match` no resultado da página, no HTML em si.

Agora, com ambos os conteúdos em mãos podemos fazer o login:

```
$EnviarLoginSenha = curl_init('http://127.0.0.1/login.php');

curl_setopt_array($EnviarLoginSenha, [
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => [
            'nome' => 'inkeliz',
            'senha' => '123456789',
            'csrf' => $csrf,
        ],
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
            'Cookie: '.$cookie
        ]
]);

curl_exec($EnviarLoginSenha);
```

O `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` é equivalente ao `-H` e o `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` quando informado uma array é equivalente ao `-d`. Então podemos fazer qualquer ação como se estivesse logado, baseado nos cookies, logo:

```
$AcessarLogado = curl_init('http://127.0.0.1/login.php');

curl_setopt_array($AcessarLogado, [
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        'Cookie: '.$cookie
    ]
]);

echo curl_exec($AcessarLogado);
```

Retornará:

```
Você está logado usando o nome de inkeliz
```

---

O conceito básico é este, pode ser aplicado em qualquer caso. É obvio que outras validações podem ser feitas, como por exemplo ter que informar um UA válido e afins.

Comment: Creio que não haverá mais respostas, então marquei como resolvido irei estudar estes conceitos que você mencionou na resposta, só uma pergunta você faz parte da equipe do Twitter?

Comment: Fiz o teste, com `php 7`, não carrega, e informa que a variável `$curl` está indefinida.

Comment: O `$curl` somente usado dentro do `CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION` e ele nunca é usado. Você precisa ter uma versão do cURL minimamente atualizada, no caso utilizei PHP 7.1 e o cURL 7.50.3, a última versão é a 7.54.1. Se tiver usando alguma versão muito antiga é esperado que ele não funcione.

Comment: Estou usando a versão 7.0.10

Comment: uma dúvida, o que devo colocar nesses campos ? `$cookie = '';
$csrf = '';` ?

Comment: Até hoje não consegui utilizar isto @Inkeliz

Comment: veja http://prntscr.com/fpbmbf/direct estou usando corretmente?

Comment: @Inkeliz, testei não obtive nenhum erro, igual WillBB informou o que devo colocar nas variáveis `$cookie = ''; $csrf = ''; $curl e $cabecalho` ?

Comment: @GuilhermeAlves este código é um código de exemplo, se souber sobre HTTP conseguirá ajustar para qualquer situação. Essas variáveis foram criadas para não causar erros de "Notice:", além disso o `$cookie` é usado como referencia `&$cookie` dentro da função do `CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION`, logo para que a referencia funcione como esperado é preciso que defina a variável antes. O primeiro código, onde existe `$PegarCSRFToken =` acho que o nome é sugestivo, ela é quem define ambas as variáveis. Para que o código funcione você precisa ter um cURL atualizado ( de preferencia 7.50+) e PHP 7.1+.

Comment: Sim, eu dei um var_dump no antes do retorno e me deu 200 OK, mas ta me dando variável indefinida $matches[1], não sei por que @Inkeliz

Comment: @Inkeliz vou abrir outra pergunta baseada nesta ta ok aí vc tenta me ajudar?

Comment: @Inkeliz veja https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/217256/curl-retornando-offset-indefinido

Comment: A pergunta é sobre OAuth/Twitter. Essa resposta explica como fazer login num site simulando um usuário num navegador, ou seja, é um webcrawler.

Comment: @rodorgas OAuth não usa login/senha, inclusive isso eu disse no comentário que foi usado para essa pergunta, no inicio do post dele. O que ele quer no "Este é meu formulário:" é justamente que o usuário insira o login e senha, como consequência não use o OAuth. Se não quer usar o OAuth terá que o usar o login/senha do Twitter, que cairá no mesmo principio desse exemplo.

Comment: Pois é, o AP está confuso sobre OAuth e busca esclarecimento. Logar no twitter usando as credenciais do usuário continua sendo uma péssima ideia...