# cURL retornando valor null no JSON com PHP

Tags: php, json, libcurl, twitter-api

Bom estou estudando `cURL`, pois quero fazer um aplicativo com o Twitter usando formulário de login e senha... ontem fiz [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/215762/como-obter-informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-para-fomul%C3%A1rio-vindo-do-twitter/215803?noredirect=1#comment441079_215803) e foi muito bem respondida, com base nisto estou estudando `cURL`, então tenho o seguinte código:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['ttrSignin'])) {
  $ttrUsername = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ttrUsername'));
  $ttrPassword = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ttrPassword'));
  $ttrTweet = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ttrTweet'));

  if (empty($ttrUsername)) {
    $error[] = 'Insira seu nome de usuário do Twitter.';
  } elseif (empty($ttrPassword)) {
    $error[] = 'Insira sua senha do Twitter.';
  } elseif (empty($ttrTweet)) {
    $error[] = 'Insira seu Tweet.';
  } else {
    # The Twitter API Address
    $url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json';

    # Versão alternativa do JSON
    # $url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json'
    # Configure e execute o processo de curl
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'status=' . $ttrTweet);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $ttrUsername . ':' . $ttrPassword);

    $buffer = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    //var_dump($buffer);

  }

  # Verifique o sucesso ou o fracasso
  if (empty($buffer)) {
    $error[] = 'Não foi possível conectar-se ao Twitter.'; 
  } else {
    $success[] = 'Tweet postado via Twitter API.';
  }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Follow</title>

    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                    <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Entrar para ganhar seguidores
                  </div>

                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <form method="post">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="ttrUsername" placeholder="Usuário do Twitter" value="<?php if (isset($error)) {echo $ttrUsername;} ?>" class="form-control">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" name="ttrPassword" placeholder="Senha do Twitter" class="form-control">
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="ttrTweet" placeholder="Digite seu Tweet" value="<?php if (isset($error)) {echo $ttrTweet;} ?>" class="form-control">
                      </div>

                      <button type="submit" name="ttrSignin" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
                        <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> Entrar agora
                      </button>
                    </form>
                  </div>

                  <div class="panel-footer">
                    <div class="text-center">
                      <small>
                        Ao entrar você estará concordando com os <a href="#">Termos de Uso</a>.
                      </small>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <?php if (isset($error)): ?>
                    <?php foreach ($error as $e): ?>
                      <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <i class="fa fa-warning"></i> <?php echo $e; ?>
                      </div>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                  <?php endif ?>

                  <?php if (isset($success)): ?>
                    <?php foreach ($success as $s): ?>
                      <div class="alert alert-success">
                        <i class="fa fa-check"></i> <?php echo $s; ?>
                      </div>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                  <?php endif ?>

                  <?php if (isset($ttrTweet)): ?>
                    <?php echo $ttrTweet; ?>
                  <?php endif ?>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Quando executado ele mostra a mensagem:

> Não foi possível conectar-se ao Twitter.

Ao dar um `var_dump($buffer);`, ele me retorna o seguinte:

> C:\wamp64\www\twitterlogin\index.php:31:boolean false

O que está errado?

Comment: Acho que por questão de segurança o Twitter não permite mais isso. *Acho*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem vários possíveis problemas:

1. Este endpoint (`https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json`) espera que envie o `access_token`, obtido usando o [OAuth](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth).

   **Solução:** Informe o `access_token`.
2. Se você não configurou o `CABundle` e estiver usando PHP 7.1 o cURL vai verificar o *emissor* do certificado com as autoridades que você confia, automaticamente. Um dos princípios do SSL é confiança, se você confia naquele que emitiu o certificado ele será seguro, *não vou entrar em detalhes aqui*.

   **Solução:**

   1. Defina as chaves publicas dos emissores que você confia, [ou um genérico](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html).
   2. Defina onde ele está armazenado:

      ```
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'C:\local\do\ca-bundle.pem');
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
      ```
3. O [`CURLOPT_USERPWD`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_USERPWD.html) é para [HTTP Authentication](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication), neste caso e que por padrão é o [Basic Access Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), se não usar o [`CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH.html). Normalmente estes dados são enviados naquelas caixinhas de *alert* pedindo login/senha, pelo navegador, o Twitter parenta não usar isso, uma vez que usa OAuth.

Comment: Estou tentando, fazer isto sem usar OAuth como mencionado por você em outra pergunta minha.

Comment: Tá agora eu não entendi, você quer autenticar o usuário sem usar OAuth? Impossível meu filho, tem como fazer formulário usando login/senha com OAuth sim.

Comment: @GuilhermeAlves tem não, não fala coisas, que não sabes.

Comment: Ainda não resolvi o problema @Inkeliz adicionei o código que você mencionou e ainda obtenho erros.

Comment: Qual erro? Você baixou o CA-Bundle especificou corretamente o local?O local do `CURLOPT_CAINFO` deve ser exato, por exemplo `__DIR__ . '\cacert-2017-06-07.pem'` [caso baixe aqui](https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert-2017-06-07.pem). Provavelmente você vai obter outro erro, mas o JSON será mostrado e escrito o motivo do erro, que é por não ter o `access_token`.

Comment: Deu certo arrumei o diretório, passou em todos, mostrou a mensagem que o tweet foi postado, mas fui olhar lá não tem nada postado. :(

Comment: Obs: percebi que mesmo digitando usuário e/ou senha incorretos, a mensagem de sucesso aparece também, agora preciso implmentar isso pra obter o token de acesso conforme dito na minha outra pergunta que vc respondeu.

Comment: Sim, porque a existente de JSON não indica que ele é válido. Dê um `var_dump()` e verá que existe erro, informado agora diretamente pelo Twitter.

Comment: `C:\wamp64\www\twitterlogin\index.php:33:string '{"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}' (length=62)` ok estou a um passo agora de conseguir o que eu quero... preciso apena do oauth_token e obter sessões e cookies.

Comment: @Inkeliz, nesse caso posso usar o twitterOAuth para gerar o token não posso? já obtive informações, já comparei login e senha, só falta o token e assim poderei gerar meus cookies e sessões de acesso ao site...