# cURL retornando offset indefinido

Tags: php, libcurl

Baseado [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/215762/como-obter-informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-para-fomul%C3%A1rio-vindo-do-twitter/215803?noredirect=1#comment444228_215803), me interessei porque algum tempo atrás eu estava fazendo um gerador de seguidor pro Twitter (troca de seguidores) e consegui... mas achei bacana a resposta do [Inkeliz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/15089/inkeliz), e estou tentando, fiz de tudo pra não pedir ajuda mas vamos lá. Temos o seguinte código, que ao dar um `var_dump` antes do `return` me retorn `HTTP 200 OK`, ok até aí tudo bem, mas está me retornando:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp64\www\teste\index.php on line 37

```
<?php

$cookie = '';
$csrf = '';

$url = 'https://twitter.com';

$getCSRFToken = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($getCSRFToken, [
        CURLOPT_URL             => $url,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST   => 'GET',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => false,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT       => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
        CURLOPT_REFERER         => $url,
        CURLOPT_HEADER          => true,
        CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION  => function($curl, $header) use (&$cookie){

            if(strpos($header, 'Set-Cookie:') === 0){
                if(preg_match('/Set-Cookie:\s?(.*?);/', $header, $matches)) {
                    $cookie .= $matches[1] . '; ';

                }
            }

            return strlen($header);
        }
    ]
);

$getCSRFToken = curl_exec($getCSRFToken);

preg_match('/name="csrf".*?value="(.*?)"/', $getCSRFToken, $matches);

$csrf = $matches[1];

if(preg_match('/name="csrf".*?value="(.*?)"/', $getCSRFToken, $matches)){
    $csrf = $matches[1];
}
```

Eu tirei `if` porque a do `if` não estava funcionando. Qual é o problema?

**PRIMEIRA EDIÇÃO:**

tirei o `if` e alterei a linha:

```
preg_match('/name="csrf".*?value="(.*?)"/', $getCSRFToken, $matches);
```

Para:

```
preg_match('/value="(.*?)" name="authenticity_token"/', $getCSRFToken, $matches);
```

**Funcionou** **:)**

Agora vem outra dúvida, como uso o valor do `return strlen($header);` para salvar `Cookies`?

Comment: O erro está nesta linha `/name="csrf".*?value="(.*?)"/` troque por `/value="(.*?)".*?name="csrf"/`

Comment: Não é, eu não ia nem testar, mas vou kk tenho certeza que não é aí

Comment: dê um `var_dump` em `$matches` antes de associar a posição 1 em `$csrf` e verifique se realmente existe a posição 1

Comment: Me retornou `array (size=0)`, mas o problema está na linha que @WillBB citou

Comment: troquei o valor do `name="csrf"` por `authenticity_token` e funcionou

Comment: mas tinha que vim mas dados...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Resumo:**

1. O `strlen($header)` não tem nada haver com pegar as informações, isso é uma exigencia do cURL.
2. A variável `$cookie`, como define a referencia `use (&$cookie)` irá ter todos os cookies.

---

Existem N maneiras de salvar o *cookie*, basicamente existe:

1. Armazenar de maneira tradicional e oficial do cURL:

   Use o `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` como indicado na documentação, ele irá salvar em um arquivo contendo todos os cookies no formato dos antigos navegadores, *pessoalmente acho esse sistema de armazenar em arquivos terrivel, porque cada vez que for usar os cookies terá que ler um arquivo em disco* e ele irá salvar todos os cookies e não os que lhe interessa.

   Depois para definir os cookies use o `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE`.
2. Armazenar no banco de dados:

   Use o `CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION` ou faça uma gambiarra ainda maior usando o `subtr` com o valor do `CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE`, mas não irá funcionar se usar um proxy, porque pode retornar um `100 Continue`.

   Depois para usar tem duas opções `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` ou `CURLOPT_COOKIE`, note é que `COOKIE` e não `COOKIEFILE`.

---

A mágica de usar o `CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION`, quando você isso:

```
    CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION  => function($curl, $header) use (&$cookie){

        if(strpos($header, 'Set-Cookie:') === 0){
            if(preg_match('/Set-Cookie:\s?(.*?);/', $header, $matches)) {
                $cookie .= $matches[1] . '; ';

            }
        }

        return strlen($header);
    }
```

O `function($curl, $header) use (&$cookie)` será executado a cada cabeçalho recebido, segundo a documentação:

> "The name of a callback function where the callback function takes two parameters. The first is the cURL resource, the second is a string with the header data to be written. The header data must be written when using this callback function. Return the number of bytes written."

Como você usa o `use (&$cookie)` o PHP irá escrever as informações no `$cookie`, que foi definida anteriormente, ou seja:

```
$variavel = '';

$funcao = function() use (&$variavel){
 $variavel = 'abc';
};

$funcao();

echo $variavel;
// Resultado: abc
```

O `&$variavel` [é uma "referencia"](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.references.php) e isso já responde sua pergunta. Mas, ainda existe o `return strlen($header);` isso é feito para que o cURL envie as demais informações, porque como documentado:

> "Return the number of bytes written."

Então se você fizer:

```
    CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION  => function($curl, $header) use (&$cookie){

        if(strpos($header, 'Set-Cookie:') === 0){
            if(preg_match('/Set-Cookie:\s?(.*?);/', $header, $matches)) {
                $cookie .= $matches[1] . '; ';

            }
        }

        return strlen($header);
    }
```

**A variável `$cookie` possuirá todos os cookies que foram obtidos.**

Em detalhes:

```
if(strpos($header, 'Set-Cookie:') === 0){
```

> Verifica se é o cabeçalho de `Set-Cookie`, afinal existem vários e vários cabeçalhos, começando por `content-encoding` e `cache-control`...

```
if(preg_match('/Set-Cookie:\s?(.*?);/', $header, $matches)) {
```

> Irá obter o valor do cookie e nome, ignorando o domínio, validade e qualquer outra informação.

---

Teste prático, executado para o `https://stackoverflow.com`:

```
/** 
    Este trecho de código possui falhas de segurança,
    não é recomendado utilizar isto, apenas para testes!
**/

$cookie = '';

$curl = curl_init('https://stackoverflow.com');
curl_setopt_array($curl, [
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => 1,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
        CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION  => function($curl, $header) use (&$cookie){
            if(stripos($header, 'Set-Cookie:') === 0){
                if(preg_match('/Set-Cookie:\s?(.*?);/i', $header, $matches)) {
                    $cookie .= $matches[1] . '; ';
                }
            }
            return strlen($header);
        }
    ]
);    
curl_exec($curl);

echo $cookie;
```

Resultado:

```
prov=afae05a0-3694-886d-fe23-fc34e5ae0b4e;
```

Se houvesse mais cookies iria ficar listado da seguinte forma:

```
nome1=valor1; nome2=valor2; (...)
```

Comment: Muito boa sua resposta, porém comigo nada funciona, o teste prático testei e não funcionou comigo, será que é meu apache... eu quero pegar os cookies do twitter...

Comment: Tente definir para `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` e `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` para `0` para verificar, isso é inseguro por isso no exemplo não usei. Vou editar.

Comment: Não funcionou, mas vou tentando aqui.

Comment: Quando executa um `var_dump(curl_error($curl))` resulta em que? Qual é do cURL usada, veja executando `var_dump(curl_version()['version']);`, se for uma versão muito antiga irá causar problemas. Eu testei em três versões 7.50 e 7.51, em Windows e 7.54.0 em CentOS.

Comment: `var_dump(curl_error($curl));` retorna uma string vazia, `var_dump(curl_version()['version']);` retorna `7.50.1`, mas funciona com o site `https://stackoverflow.com` agora `https://twitter.com` não funciona porque será?

Comment: O twitter usa o `set-cookies` e não `Set-Cookies`, vou editar para suportar isso nas duas respostas. Não sei se tem alguma RFC dizendo se deve ser maiúsculo ou não, fiquei curioso agora. Vou editar em breve.

Comment: Oshe sem sucesso também... vou dar uma pesquisada. EDIT: o twitter usa `set-cookie` sem **s** no final e tudo minusculo

Comment: Vamos no xat pra vc tirar algumas dúvidas minha?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61424/discussion-between-guilherme-alves-and-inkeliz).