# HTTP/1.1 302 Found É normal ou está com problema?

Tags: php, libcurl, twitter-api

Estou tento o seguinte retorno no meu código `PHP`, que inclusive com esses tópicos me ajudaram muito: [Primeiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/215762/como-obter-informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-para-fomul%C3%A1rio-vindo-do-twitter), [Segundo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/217256/curl-retornando-offset-indefinido)

> C:\wamp64\www\teste\index.php:61:string 'HTTP/1.1 302 Found
>   cache-control: no-cache, max-age=300
>   content-length: 157
>   content-security-policy: default-src 'none'; connect-src 'self'; font-src https://abs.twimg.com https://abs-0.twimg.com data:; frame-src 'self' twitter:; frame-ancestors 'self' https://tweetdeck.twitter.com https://tdapi-staging.smf1.twitter.com https://tdapi-staging.atla.twitter.com https://tweetdeck.localhost.twitter.com; img-src https://abs.twimg.com https://*.twimg.com https://pbs.twimg.com data:; media-src 'none'; object-src'... (length=116072)

Meu código PHP:

```
<?php

$cookie = [];

$index_url = 'https://twitter.com';

$token = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($token, [
      CURLOPT_URL             => $index_url,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST   => 'GET',
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => false,
      CURLOPT_USERAGENT       => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
      CURLOPT_REFERER         => $index_url,
      CURLOPT_HEADER          => TRUE,
      CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION  => function($curl, $header) use (&$cookie){
          if(stripos($header, 'Set-Cookie:') === 0){
              if(preg_match('/Set-Cookie:\s?(.*?);/i', $header, $matches)) {
                  // $cookie .= $matches[1] . '; ';
                  $cookie[] = $matches[1];
              }
          }
          //var_dump($header);
          return strlen($header);
      }
    ]
);    
$access = curl_exec($token);

preg_match('/value="(.*?)" name="authenticity_token"/', $access, $matches);

$authenticity_token = $matches[1];

//how to use cookie array
//$cookie[0];

$username = 'jhonesstevan';
$password = 'laranjao1020';

$session_post = "session[username_or_email]=$username&session[password]=$password&return_to_ssl=true&scribe_log=&redirect_after_login=%2F&authenticity_token=$authenticity_token";

$session_url = 'https://twitter.com/sessions';

curl_setopt_array($token, [
      CURLOPT_URL             => $session_url,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST   => 'POST',
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => $session_post,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER      => [
        "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      ],
      CURLOPT_USERAGENT       => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
      CURLOPT_HEADER          => TRUE,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => 1,
  ]

);
$auth = curl_exec($token);

var_dump($auth);
```

Comment: PS: Conta fake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É normal, ele indica apenas que a página foi "movida" e o `Location:` indicará para onde o usuário deve ir.

---

Esta publicação do Wikipédia sobre os códigos do HTTP é suficiente para responder:

> ## 3xx Redirecionamento
>
> **302 Encontrado**
>
> Este é um exemplo de boas práticas industriais contradizendo a norma.
>   especificação HTTP/1.0 (RFC 1945) exigiu o cliente para executar um
>   redirecionamento temporário (o que descreve frase original era "Movido
>   Temporariamente"), mas os browsers populares executadas 302 com a
>   funcionalidade de um 303 Consulte Outros. Por isso, acrescentou
>   HTTP/1.1 códigos de status 303 e 307 a distinguir entre os dois
>   comportamentos. No entanto, a maioria das aplicações Web e os quadros
>   ainda usam o código de status 302 como se fosse o 303.

[Fonte](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_c%C3%B3digos_de_estado_HTTP#302_Encontrado)

---

O cURL por padrão não irá seguir redirecionamentos, isso é uma prática um tanto quanto insegura, mesmo com as limitações padrões do cURL.

Para habilitar redirecionamentos (seguir o cabeçalho de `Location:`):

```
curl_setopt_array($token, [
     //...
     CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true
]
```

Para que defina o limite de redirecionamentos pode usar o `CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS`, onde o `10` é o limite definido por mim, caso seja `-1` será ilimitado:

```
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10
```

Para definir quais protocolos podem ser usados, por exemplo `HTTP`e `HTTPS`:

```
CURLOPT_REDIR_PROTOCOLS => CURLPROTO_HTTP | CURLPROTO_HTTPS
```

Para que use o mesmo método para o redirecionamento utilize o comando abaixo, com isso se fizer um POST ele (e o conteúdo enviado) será enviado para o local redirecionado:

```
CURLOPT_POSTREDIR => 2
```

Se quiser que o cURL atualize o `referer` baseado no `Location` pode também utilizar:

```
CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => 1
```

---

Usando o `CURLOPT_HEADER => TRUE` você vai obter todos os cabeçalhos, de todas as requisições feitas, isso pode explicar o motivo de que:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
//...

HTTP/1.1 200 Ok
//...
```

Isso indica que a primeira requisição retornou `302` e a segunda `200`, por exemplo. Logicamente pode ocorrer de ser `302` -> `404`, ou `302` -> `403`.

Além disso se quiser obter o URL da última requisição feita, poderá utilizar também o comando:

```
echo curl_getinfo($token, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
```

Se quiser obter o último HTTP poderá utilizar também:

```
echo curl_getinfo($token, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

---

Por padrão o cURL não permite redirecionamentos para o protocolo `file` e `SCP` na versão 7.19.4 e na versão 7.40.0 o protocolo de `SMB` e `SMBS` também não são seguidos. Porém todo o resto é seguido, inclusive o `gopher`, `stmp`, `ftp`, o que pode ser um risco em potencial, *mas acho que não cabe aqui esse assunto*.

Comment: Opa, valeu, eu estou lendo a documentação sobre cRL, deveriam informar lá, fiz o que você colocou na resposta, e continua ainda 302, mas li alguns artigos e é normal.

Comment: Eles informam isso claramente, `-L, --location: If the server reports that the requested page has moved to a different location (indicated with a Location: header and a 3XX response code), this option will make curl redo the request on the new place.`, em https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html. Usar o `FOLLOWLOCATION` vai permitir que ele siga o caminho, como documentado. Para que isso ocorra é preciso que tenha o `Location:` e que seja `3XX`.

Comment: Ta preciso definir `--max-redirs <num>` para `-1` e não encontrei o CURL que faz isto.

Comment: Isso é equivalente ao `CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS` e é opcional.

Comment: sim mas torna ilimitado conforme diz na documentação, eu só queria remover essa mensagem e deixar 200 OK mas tá dificil

Comment: Editei para adicionar mais detalhes, acredito que agora tem todos os comandos em relação a redirecionamento, embora não necessariamente vão corrigir o problema.

Comment: Feito: me retornou `https://twitter.com/login/error?username_or_email=jhonesstevan&redirect_after_login=%2F`

Comment: Então ele seguiu o redirecionamento normalmente, afinal você fez a requisição para `https://twitter.com/sessions`. Este então não é o problema. Talvez o problema seja porque não definiu os cookies obtidos na antiga requisição, mas isso é outra questão.

Comment: sim codigo está 200 `echo curl_getinfo($token, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);` ta ok agora :D

Comment: Porém eu não obtenho todos os cookies do Twitter, porque será?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61427/discussion-between-inkeliz-and-guilherme-alves).