# Netscape HTTP Cookie File - Usar arquivo salvo?

Tags: php, libcurl

Galera minha dúvida é básica, mas tem um porém, pesquisei e não achei a explicação, no site da documentação do `cURL` explica mas mesmo eu traduzindo não entendi. Bom vamos lá.

`CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`  Salva o arquivo em um diretório qualquer.

`CURLOPT_COOKIFILE` Lê o arquivo no diretório salvo, estou correto?

`CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION` Inicia a sessão do `COOKIEJAR` correto ou não?

Me ajudem com essas dúvidas antes de responderem a de baixo:

Depois de salvo os `COOKIES` no arquivo, como uso ele sem ter que armazenar em `setcookie();` ?

Como uso estás funções do `cURL` corretamente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem quatro funções de leitura (e um de gravação que é o `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`, oficialmente e um *info* que é o `CURLINFO_COOKIELIST`, que informa no formato `Set-Cookie`, explicado abaixo):

### CURLOPT_COOKIE

Ele é um atalho para `-H "Cookie: {string}"`. Ele define o valor (string) diretamente no cabeçalho do `Cookie:`, pressupõe que siga a [RFC 6265 (veja sessão 3.1)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-3.1), portanto:

> **Servidor -> Usuário: (Entenda como "Formato do Set-Cookie"):**

> Set-Cookie: SID=31d4d96e407aad42; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
> Set-Cookie: lang=en-US; Path=/; Domain=example.com

> **Usuário -> Servidor: (Entenda como "Formato do Cookie"):**

> Cookie: SID=31d4d96e407aad42; lang=en-US

Para múltiplos cookies se utiliza `;` entre cada valor, no caso do cliente e no caso do servidor utiliza múltiplos `Set-Cookie:`.

O cURL age como um `Usuário -> Servidor`, neste caso e usando o `CURLOPT_COOKIE` você precisará seguir o formato do "Cookie".

---

*As funções abaixo utilizam o "cookie engine", o sistema de gerenciamento do cookies do próprio cURL:*

### CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE

Define o `Cookie:` usando as informações de um arquivo. Esse arquivo pode estar em dois formatos, pode usar o formato do [antigo Netscape](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/215513/pra-que-serve-e-como-usar-netscape-http-cookie-file/215518#215518) ou pode ter o mesmo formato do `Set-Cookie`, explicado acima.

---

### CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION

Ele irá remover qualquer cookie "de sessão", criando assim uma nova sessão, simulando por exemplo que fechou o navegador e abriu novamente.

Caso utilize outras funções que usem o "cookie engine" (tais como `COOKIEFILE` e o `COOKIELIST`) ele pode conter as flags, tais flags vão indicar o tempo de expiração dele. Se ele for `0` (ou omitido) ele será considerado um cookie não-permanente, em outras palavras será "um cookie de sessão", como definido nesta mesma [RFC (veja 5.3: Storage Model)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.3):

> When "the current session is over" (as defined by the user agent),
> the user agent MUST remove from the cookie store all cookies with the
> persistent-flag set to false.

---

### CURLOPT_COOKIELIST

Ele permite importar uma string (tanto no formato Netscape, quanto no formato `Set-Cookie`). A diferença dele para o `CURLOPT_COOKIE` é que permite usar o formato do `Set-Cookie` e não do `Cookie`. Além disso caso utilize o `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` ele irá salvar os cookies, inclusive os definidos por você.

Existem alguns detalhes, ele irá manter sempre o cookie que foi definido antes, ou seja se der um `COOKELIST` antes do `COOKIEFILE` e houver conflito de nomes o primeiro ficará vivo, o que não ocorre no `CURLOPT_COOKIE`, afinal ele não usa o gerenciamento de cookies. Além disso existem alguns comandos especiais, quando se utiliza as strings de `FLUSH`, `RELOAD`, `SESS` e `ALL`.

---

Isso é um resumo, [toda a documentação detalhada está na própria página do cURL](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html), que é bem melhor que a documentação do PHP, diga-se de passagem.

---

**Depois de salvo os COOKIES no arquivo, como uso ele sem ter que armazenar em setcookie(); ?**

Nunca precisou usar o `setcookie`, isso apenas cria um cookie entre você e o seu cliente, isso não faz menor sentido. Afinal, agora o cliente poderá controlar um cookie que será utilizado pelo seu cURL.

Você pode armazenar em qualquer local, na verdade se ele já está salvo num arquivo ele já está armazenado. Para utiliza-lo depende do formato em que o conteúdo desse arquivo está. Se estiver em formato Netscape poderá usar `_COOKIEFILE`, se estiver no formato `Set-Cookie` poderá usar o `_COOKIELIST`. Já se estiver no formato `Cookie` poderá usar `_COOKIE` ou usar diretamente o `-H "Cookie: ..."`.

Assim como poderá extrair as informações diretamente do header e armazenar do banco de dados, tanto no formato `Set-Cookie` quanto no formato `Cookie`. Enfim, como armazenar é por sua conta. O seu navegador, por exemplo, armazena os cookie de uma forma, que pode ser totalmente diferente de vários arquivos... O armazenamento não importa, o que importa é enviar (quando necessário) os cookies corretos e apagar os cookies quando necessário.

**Como uso estás funções do cURL corretamente?**

Sabendo o que cada uma faz poderá saber qual utiliza-la ou não utilizar nenhuma, todas essas funções são apenas "atalhos", recursos já embutidos para facilitar o uso de cookies. Mas isso pode não facilitar em todos os casos, você pode criar o seu próprio sistema de gerenciamento de cookies. Afinal os cookies é (e sempre será) apenas um mero cabeçalho com um valor arbitrário seguindo o `Nome=Valor`, no caso de comunicação entre cliente para o servidor (ou do cURL para o servidor, nessa situação), então qualquer coisa que insira esse cabeçalho dará certo.

Comment: Opa então quando eu monitoro um certo site e vejo lá Cookie: ... Devo usar `_COOKIE` ao invés de `_COOKIEFILE`?