# Curl cookies expires vs n/a

Tags: php, libcurl, cookies

A dúvida é o seguinte, no `network` do console do navegador diz que os cookies não expiram, vejam a imagem a baixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém ao pegar (fazer um request destes) estes cookies com `curl` expiram:

> ct0=e3197b1390ba24c4ae827fc6740344fa; Expires=Mon, 23 Oct 2017
>   14:21:33 UTC; Path=/; Domain=.twitter.com; Secure

Hoje as `14:21:33` eles já não funcionam mais. Como estou pegando estes cookies?

Assim:

```
$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->cookies = '';
$obj->location = '';

$request = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($request, [
        CURLOPT_URL                         => 'https://twitter.com/',
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST       => 'GET',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
        CURLOPT_HEADER                  => true,
        CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR               => getcwd() . '/cookies/' . $username . '.txt',
        CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION  => function($curl, $header) use (&$obj) {
            if (stripos($header, 'Set-Cookie:') === 0) {
                if (preg_match('/^Set-Cookie: \s*([^=]*)=([^;]*)/mi', $header, $matches)) {
                    $obj->cookies .= $matches[1] . '=' . $matches[2] . '; ';
                    $obj->{$matches[1]} = $matches[2];
                }
            }
            var_dump($header);
            return strlen($header);
        }
    ]
);
$response = curl_exec($request);
```

Sendo que:

```
if (stripos($header, 'Set-Cookie:') === 0) {
    if (preg_match('/^Set-Cookie: \s*([^=]*)=([^;]*)/mi', $header, $matches)) {
        $obj->cookies .= $matches[1] . '=' . $matches[2] . '; ';
        $obj->{$matches[1]} = $matches[2];
    }
}
```

Já fária o trabalho pra eles não expirar correto?

### EDITADO

Na documentação eu traduzi e diz o seguinte:

> O Curl possui um motor de análise de cookies integrado incorporado que
>   vem em uso se você quiser se reconectar a um servidor e usar cookies
>   que foram armazenados em uma conexão anterior (ou manualmente
>   manualmente para enganar o servidor para acreditar que você teve uma
>   conexão anterior ). Para usar cookies armazenados anteriormente, você
>   executa curl como:
>
> curl --cookie stored_cookies_in_file http://www.example.com

E aqui que está o que eu quero:

> se você quiser se reconectar a um servidor e usar cookies que foram
>   armazenados em uma conexão anterior

Ta como eu faço isso no PHP ?

Comment: "O Curl possui um motor de análise de cookies", somente o `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`, `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE`, `CURLOPT_COOKIELIST` e o `CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION` utilizam o gerenciador de cookies do cURL, a função cima não usa, isso já foi dito diversas vezes inclusive. O código mencionado acima ignora completamente o tempo de expiração, ela apenas obtêm o nome e o valor. Inclusive, parte das perguntas talvez esteja [respondidas aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/234444/netscape-http-cookie-file-usar-arquivo-salvo/).

Comment: @Inkeliz, está correto, mas o que eu não entendo é do porque que os cookies do Instagram eu consigo usar vários meses, e o do twitter não consigo usar depois de horas.

Comment: O equivalente `ct0` do Instagram é o `csrftoken`, ele não liga para o valor, desde que o `csrftoken` seja o mesmo valor do header `x-csrftoken`, se ambos forem `1` será válido, por exemplo. O Twitter pode ter outro mecanismo, atualizando o valor periodicamente, inclusive associado a sessão.

Comment: Sim sim @Inkeliz, Eu monitorei lá o do twitter, expira em poucas horas, enquanto do instagram expira em 2018

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentação no site do PHP sobre o `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE`:

> The name of the file containing the cookie data. The cookie file can
>   be in Netscape format, or just plain HTTP-style headers dumped into a
>   file. If the name is an empty string, no cookies are loaded, but
>   cookie handling is still enabled.

E nessa parte:

> If the name is an empty string, no cookies are loaded, but
>   cookie handling is still enabled.

Função na qual a citação acima se referencia:

```
bool curl_setopt ( resource $ch , int $option , mixed $value )
```

Então adicione `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` com o mesmo endereço do `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`, para que os cookies sejam carregados.

Clique [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17531986/reuse-cookie-curl-php) para uma resposta similar a sua.
Clique [aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.curl-setopt.php) para a documentação do `curl options php`

Comment: Eu fiz isto, e parou de salvar alguns cookies no arquivo `.txt`, então retirei, com o `instagram` até agora todos funcionam faz 2 dias, do twitter não. Mas lendo a sua resposta estou quase perto, vou esperar mais um pouco se eu conseguir resolver com base na sua resposta marcarei como resolvido ok? e pagarei a recomepnsa!